# Cutting shapes from image

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, java-2d, clipping

I have a Buffered Image, and an array of shapes like puzzle pieces. I want to cut those shapes from the image. I tried clipping image but it doesn't work properly. What I've done so far is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            Area area = areas[i][j];
            int width = (int) area.getBounds2D().getWidth();
            int height = (int) area.getBounds2D().getHeight();

            pieces[i][j] = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());
            Graphics2D gr = pieces[i][j].createGraphics();
            gr.setClip(area);
            gr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            gr.dispose();

            try {
                ImageIO.write(pieces[i][j], "png", new File("img/img" + i + "" + j + ".png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

It only works for the first shape, then it writes transparent images as output.

Comment: Did you check that the intersection of the Area objects with the image bounds is not empty? (that is, the shapes are over the image, and not somewhere else or empty)

Comment: I think it would help us better understand the question, if you show the image you want to clip, and print a couple of the `Area`s. Do you simply want to extract sub-images like @Glains thinks, or do you actually want to clip a single image into multiple shapes like @lbalazscs thinks? :-)

Comment: It's definitely necessary that you add the details of at least some of the shapes to the question. The first shape that succeeds, and a couple of ones that don't. Include the data that creates shape and also which `i` and `j` it is.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are plenty of methods to do this. Here is my approach :)

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;
int rows = 0;
int columns = 0;
BufferedImage sheet = // you image goes here 
BufferedImage[] pieces = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        pieces[(i * cols) + j] = sheet.getSubimage(j * width, i * height, width, height);    
    }
}
```

Note that the pieces are all in one array. If you still want your pieces in a two-dimensional array:

```
// Switch these lines
BufferedImage[][] pieces = new BufferedImage[rows][cols];
pieces[i][j] = sheet.getSubimage(j * width, i * height, width, height);
```

**Additional Reading:** Spritesheets and Animation 
Click [here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-spritesheet-animation--gamedev-13099)!

Comment: If you want to have dynamic methods to calculate the width and height for 1 piece just call `int width = sheet.getWidth() / colums;` but you have to put the sheet declaration on top of the calculation to make this work.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer misses the point of the OP, who (as far as I understand) wants to cut out non-rectangular shapes

Comment: I have understood something else from the question text, but i am sorry if this is not the exact answer. For  a more detailed one i need a clearer question and eventually the given image and the preferred result. (puzzle pieces are normally a square so this should work)